# Telerik Radlistview dynamically grouping items

Tags: c#, telerik

using winform I am trying to display  from database the fooditems that are grouped under categories into a radlistview using that below code; but the Problem that it is showing the main Groups but not showing the items under it.

```
  ZalaqEntities1 zlq=new ZalaqEntities1();

        List<cat> cats = zlq.cats.ToList();
        radListView1.Items.Clear();
        radListView1.Groups.Clear();
        radListView1.EnableGrouping = true;
        radListView1.ShowGroups = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < cats.Count(); i++)
        {
            radListView1.Groups.Add(new ListViewDataItemGroup());
            radListView1.Groups[i].Value = cats[i].catname;
            radListView1.Groups[i].Key = cats[i].catid;


        }

        List<fooditem> fooditems = zlq.fooditems1.ToList();
        for (int j = 0; j < fooditems.Count(); j++)
        {
            ListViewDataItem myitem = new ListViewDataItem();
            myitem.Value = fooditems[j].itemname;
            myitem.Key = fooditems[j].itemid;
           // myitem.Group = radListView1.Groups[1];
            radListView1.Items.Add(myitem);
            myitem.Group = radListView1.Groups.Where(i => i.Key == fooditems[j].catid).FirstOrDefault();
            //radListView1.Items[j].Group = radListView1.Groups[1];
        }
        radListView1.Refresh();
```

I am trying to add the Item under its category using the where condition to find the correct group by its Key.

If I do this outside for Loop it was working for adding several Items.but from database inside the for loop non.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was just by casting the i.Key.ToString() inside the Where Clause ..

the Final Code :

```
      ZalaqEntities1 zlq=new ZalaqEntities1();

        List<cat> cats = zlq.cats.ToList();
        radListView1.Items.Clear();
        radListView1.Groups.Clear();
        radListView1.EnableGrouping = true;
        radListView1.ShowGroups = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < cats.Count(); i++)
        {
            ListViewDataItemGroup grp = new ListViewDataItemGroup();
            grp.Value = cats[i].catname;
            grp.Key = cats[i].catid.ToString();
            radListView1.Groups.Add(grp);
            radListView1.Groups[i].Key = cats[i].catid;
         }
        radListView1.Refresh();
          List<fooditem> mfooditems = zlq.fooditems1.ToList();
        for (int j = 0; j < mfooditems.Count(); j++)
        {
            ListViewDataItem myitem = new ListViewDataItem();
            myitem.Value = mfooditems[j].itemname;
            myitem.Key = mfooditems[j].itemid;
             radListView1.Items.Add(myitem);
            radListView1.Refresh();
            radListView1.Items[j].Group = radListView1.Groups.Where(i => i.Key.ToString() == mfooditems[j].catid.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();

        }
        radListView1.Refresh();
```